# Create class from form object

Tags: class, object, designer, foxpro, visual-foxpro

Using Visual Foxpro 9, I have a complicated grid (currently on a .scx-based form) which I would like to convert into a class (.vcx, not .prg) so I can re-use the grid on other forms.  I really don't want to have to create the grid (and its numerous properties) from scratch if it can be avoided.  I was looking for something like copying or dragging the grid from the form-designer to the class-browser, but can't find anything that works for me.

Any help appreciated.

Alan

Answer (score 1):

Found it - there is a 'Save As Class' option under the 'File' menu.

Regards,
Alan